# Using Like to distinguish strings with partially same fomat

Tags: vba, excel

So, we create project files for every project. A filename will contain 3 values, Project number, Client name, PO number. For example; "123456 - McDonalds - 789AB". Now, a Project Number will not always be present. Meaning its either requested or has to be requested. "McDonalds - 789AB". Every month I want a list of projects that are ongoing (Already have a project number) and pending (Don't have a project number). So I created a macro that lists all the files in my project directory. This works perfect, but now I want to make the distinguished list of both types. Problem is, when using the 'Like' function, the pattern for the extended string is always present in both types (Client name, PO number) so only 1 list will be correct while the other still is a full list.
I'm using 2 matching functions to do this.

```
Function Match1(xFile As Object, Index1 As Long, xMatch As Boolean)
xMatch = xFile.Name Like "?*[ ][-][ ]?*"
If xMatch = True Then
  Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(Index1, 1).Formula = xFile.Name
  Index1 = Index1 + 1
End If
xMatch = False
End Function

Function Match2(xFile As Object, Index2 As Long, xMatch As Boolean)
xMatch = xFile.Name Like "######[ ][-][ ]?*[ ][-][ ]?*"
If xMatch = True Then
  Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(Index2 , 6).Formula = xFile.Name
  Index2 = Index2 + 1
End If
xMatch = False
End Function
```

So when "McDonalds - 789AB" is being matched, it will come back as a match for both these functions. Is there a way to make this work? To make this a little easier, the Project Number is always 6 digits.
If more information is needed I can provide this, but I think the general questions is clear now.

Comment: One option would be to use Split (delimiter '-') and compare the individual elements.

Comment: I used an if loop to make sure that when Match2 was true I wouldn't be send through Match1. This works, but in the future more information will be added to the strings to create more specific lists. That's why I want this way to work properly.

Comment: if you use Split you don't need two functions.

Comment: @SJR No need to even compare the elements? Just test how many array elements are returned: if there's one element or two (one dash or two dashes).

Comment: @SJR I'm not sure this would work. This way I can only compare the first element, the ###### number, since the others can be anything.

Comment: @CindyMeister - yes that's the way I see it, as per second comment, but OP might need to check format of other elements, not sure.

Comment: @SJR and CindyMeister Thanks for the input, I'm going to test these options. Will post results later.

Comment: Is there any reason you're writing these as Functions, rather than Subs?

Comment: @CLR No, since im quite new to programming in general I just roll with what I know. Is there any reason these should be subs instead of functions?

Comment: They will work like this.. it just looks odd as traditionally a `Function` is used to return a value - something you must realise as you force the value to `False`. Whereas a Sub doesn't require this. Also, I think you're using the parameter line to declare `xMatch` - again, I guess this works but seems odd (to me at least).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
Sub matchfile(xFile As Object)

    Dim outputcolumn As Long, myArr

    myArr = Split(xFile.Name, " - ")

    If UBound(myArr) = 2 Then     'if 2, then 3 items are found (0, 1 and 2)
        If myArr(0) Like "######" And myArr(2) Like "###??" Then 
            outputcolumn = 1
        End If
    ElseIf UBound(myArr) = 1 Then     'if 1, then 2 items are found (0 and 1)
        If myArr(1) Like "###??" Then
            outputcolumn = 6
        End If
    End If

    With Application.ActiveSheet
        If outputcolumn > 0 Then .Cells(1 + .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, outputcolumn).Formula = xFile.Name
    End With

End Sub
```

To call this, you would just use:

```
matchfile [fileobject]
```

It would then split the file by `"[ ]-[ ]"`, and where 3 items are found it then tests the 3rd item matches `"###??"`. Where 2 items are found it just tests the 2nd for `"###??"`. If the tests are positive, it assigns a value to `outputcolumn` - either 1 or 6 judging from your code and writes the filename to the next available cell in column `outputcolumn`.